# Restore a removed virtualenv

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Can I restore a virtual environment after it has been removed with the shell command `$rmvirtualenv my_venv`?

I can't find anything about it by searching online.

Does anything like requirements.txt get left behind from old environments?

Comment: It (virtualenvwrapper) creates and removes directories in `~/Envs` (may vary). So you need to look for a way to restore a folder

Comment: Thanks. These virtual environments are in `~/.virtualenvs`. There is no obvious sign of it in that folder nor in the Rubbish Bin.

Answer (score 1):

By deleting the folder of your virtual environment, you've deleted the virtual environment itself.

According to [`virtualenvwrapper` documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#rmvirtualenv):

> `rmvirtualenv`
>
> *Remove an environment, in the WORKON_HOME.*

but it doesn't mention anything related to settings or any file that could possibly retrieve your deleted environment. However, I would encourage you to explore *WORKON_HOME* to see if there's anything useful to recover your lost environment. Though, I've never used `virtualenvwrapper` as an extension to `virtualenv`, I use `virtualenv` standalone instead.

From [`virtualenv` documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#removing-an-environment):

> *Removing an Environment*
>
> *Removing a virtual environment is simply done by deactivating it and deleting the environment folder with all its contents:*
>
> ```
> (ENV)$ deactivate
> $ rm -r /path/to/ENV
> ```

In other words, once you delete the environment folder, the environment doesn't exist anymore, unless you have a copy of the environment folder somewhere or you're able to recover it from trash, you might be able to access the virtual environment from there. So far I cannot see any recovery option from `virtualenv`.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks. The directory did not go to the rubbish bin and I don't think that requirements.txt is stored anywhere.